# Не сохраняет данные в MySQL (Ajax, php)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, form

С формы необходимо отправить данные в БД и вывести на экране. Программа почему-то считывает пустые значения с `input`/`textarea`.  В БД сохраняются пустые значения. Не могу найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо

index.php

```
<form method="post">
     <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input rows="1" cols="25" name="inputMessage" class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter yout message" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <button type ="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
                </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

main.js - здесь запрос ajax

```
$(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                 var inputMessage = $('#inputMessage').val();
                console.log(inputMessage);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: "messages.php",
                    data: "inputMessage=" + inputMessage,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert("form was submitted");
                        $('.perepiska-content').html(response);
                           }
                });
            });
     return false;
        });
```

messages.php - Вставка в БД и вывод на экран

```
<?php 
<?php 
$db_host='localhost';
$db_user='root';
$db_pass='';
$db_database='db_shop';
$link=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_database, $link) or die("No Connection to Database".mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET names latin1");


$inputMessage=$_POST['inputMessage']; //question
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //date of question


    $query1="INSERT INTO chat_questions (question, date_question) VALUES ('$inputMessage', '$date')";
      $result1=mysql_query($query1, $link);  
        echo ' <div class="showQuestion">
                 <div class="showQuestionContent">
              </div>';

?>
?>
```

Comment: Не клик по кнопке надо обрабатывать, а `$("form").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам "SET names latin1" ?
mysql_query устарело где-то в php 5.5, стоит использовать mysqli

```
<form method="post" action="messages.php">
         <div class="row justify-content-start">
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input rows="1" cols="25" name="inputMessage" class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Enter yout message" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <button type ="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
                    </div>
         </div>
    </form>
<?php 
require_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['inputMessage']))
{
$inputMessage = $_POST(['inputMessage']);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$SQL = "INSERT INTO chat_questions (question, date_question) VALUES ('$inputMessage', '$date')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);

if ($result) {
  header('Location:index.php');
}
else {
    printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
}

?>
```

Файл db.php:

```
    <?php

//Параметры подключения в БД
$host = "localhost"; //имя хоста
$database = ""; //имя базы
$user = ""; //пользователь
$password = ""; //пароль
$dbtable = ""; //таблица

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

?>
```